# jQuery each - first variable doesn't get the width value on (some) refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a very unusual problem that I couldn't solve for hours. I have a slideshow with images. I want to center these images in the slideshow div, with the "minus margin-left method", but the first image SOMETIMES can't get the width value, so the margin-left attribute gets 0 and this means that half of the first image is hanging out of the div.

This is the jQuery code that I wrote (this code is at the end of my document):

```
$('.slider img').each(function() {      
    var iw = $(this).width();
    ih = $(this).height();    
    $(this).css({
        'left' : '50%',
        'margin-left' : '-'+iw/2+'px'
    });
});
```

Any ideas what's wrong with my code? (and sorry for my bad english).

Comment: have you wrapped that code on `$( document ).ready()` ?

Comment: If you just need this for centring the images you might look at a non-js solution and avoid this altogether. For example: `.slider {width:100%; position:relative;} .slider img {position:absolute; left:0; right:0; margin:auto;}`. Post some HTML markup for the slider. Maybe we can find a better way.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because the images has not yet loaded, so one solution is to use a load callback where you can do the calculation

```
$('.slider img').load(function () {

    var iw = $(this).width();
    var ih = $(this).height();

    $(this).css({
        'left': '50%',
        'margin-left': '-' + iw / 2 + 'px'
    });


}).filter(function () {
    //if the element is already loaded manually trigger the event
    return this.complete
}).trigger('load');
```

Answer (score 0):

Or DOM is not loaded complete, or invisible elements with `display: none` are intercepted your code.

If you try to get width and height of a `display:none` element, I recommend you to put `display:block` and `visibility:hidden`.

With this info, I can't help you more